# Как войти под рутом?

Tags: debian, linux

Всегда пользовался просто Debian, а тут при инсталляции поставил галочку Debian Graphical Environment, и оказалось, что она устанавливает GUI.

1. Не могу понять, как мне войти в GUI рутом. Есть ли там аналог sudo. В списке пользователей только мой обычный юзер, а когда пытаюсь ввести рут-пароль рута - говорит failure как будто бы и нет рута, хотя в Terminal, конечно, все работает ок.
2. Как называется разновидность GUI, которую я установил? Там вроде разные есть.
3. Тут даже шире вопрос. Как работать под рутом. Оказалось, что если я вхожу под своим юзером, то мои экспорты в /root/.bashrc не выполняются. Естественно. Все это неудобно, так как я не хочу работать под обычным юзером и возиться с правами. Как бы мне это обойти?

Comment: Рут выдается на некоторое время в целях безопасности. Вы пробовали запустить ваш обозреватель от su хотя бы из консоли?

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Какой обозреватель? Я играюст с Джава-приложениями и сетями в командной строке, мне не нужны все эти сложности с доступом.

Comment: Большинство приложений в debian по умолчанию запускается без рут-прав. Если вы хотите дать ему рут-права, запустите из консоли это приложение с помощью sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Обычно в Linux не работают под рутом, это сопряжено с ненулевой вероятностью угробить систему неосторожными действиями. Именно поэтому графические среды просто не дают залогиниться под рутом.
2. ЕМНИП по дефолту в Debian ставится GNOME 3 (он же GNOME Shell).
3. Всё-таки подумайте над тем, чтобы работать под обычным юзером. Вряд ли каждое ваше действие требует рутовых прав. Если же вам всё ещё зачем-то нужен перманентный рут, то есть 2 пути: либо печатаете в консоли `su` (без аргументов), набираете пароль рута и получаете рутовый шеллл, либо вместо графического логина осуществляете консольный (`Ctrl+Alt+F1`). Оттуда, возможно, удастся запустить графическое окружение из-под рута (хотя многие блокируют такую возможность).

Comment: Не знаю, как в debian, а в ubuntu (насколько мне известно, они достаточно схожи) одному из login-ов я (для эксперимента, поскольку по умолчанию у рута там даже нет пароля и напрямую им не войти) просто  сменил в `/etc/passwd` uid и gid на 0. 

Вроде бы работает...

На практике же, если нужно выполнить достаточно много действий от рута, я просто пишу в окошке `sudo bash` и работаю.